# php include id other database

Tags: php, sql, database

I have two database ( first : identity, second : order), i try to take my id from the first for include in the second, when the costumer order in the second database we can see the id associate.

i try a lot but nothing !

here is my php :

```
<?php
session_start();
// on teste si le visiteur a soumis le formulaire
if (isset($_POST['commande']) && $_POST['commande'] == 'commande') {
// on teste l'existence de nos variables. On teste également si elles ne sont pas vides
    if ((isset($_POST['homme']) && !empty($_POST['homme'])) && (isset($_POST['quantiteh']) && !empty($_POST['quantiteh']))) {
// on teste les deux mots de passe

        $base = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'acces_site', 'password');
        mysql_select_db ('carole', $base);

        $homme = $_POST['homme'];
        $quantiteh = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['quantiteh']);
        // $id ='SELECT id, id FROM carole,commande ';
        $id=$_SESSION['id'];



    $sql = 'INSERT INTO commande (id_commande,id,homme,quantiteh) VALUES ("", "$id", "$homme", "$quantiteh")';
    mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br />'.mysql_error());


}
}
?>
```

here is my html :

```
<fieldset id="rows0">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <form  method="POST" action="#">
                                    <select id="homme" name="homme" class="col-xs-5 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                                         <option value="chemise">Chemise</option>
                                         <option value="chemise pliée">Chemise pliée</option>
                                         <option value="veste">Veste</option>
                                         <option value="pantalon">Pantalon</option>
                                         <option value="cravate">Cravate</option>
                                         <option value="pull">Pull, Gilet</option>
                                         <option value="blouson">Blouson</option>
                                         <option value="blouson">Blouson 3/4</option>
                                         <option value="impermable">Imperméable</option>
                                         <option value="manteau">Manteau</option>
                                         <option value="doudoune">Doudoune</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="number" min="1" id="quantiteh" name="quantiteh" placeholder="Quantité" class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-lg-4"/>
                                    <button type ="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="commande" value="commande">Continuer</button>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset id="controls">
                            <button id="addRow0">add</button>
                            <button id="removeRow0" disabled>remove</button>
                        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you post mysql error here?

Comment: can you explain what do you want? if you have any error post it with question

Comment: i want to select id from the first database for include it on the second when consumer make an order i want to have id ( from first table) column

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not expanded when used in a string enclosed with single quotes.

So this will not work:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO commande (id_commande,id,homme,quantiteh) VALUES ("", "$id", "$homme", "$quantiteh")';
                                                                           ^^^ no variable here, just the string "$id", etc.
```

You could switch the single quotes for double ones and the double ones for single ones, but then you'd have an sql injection problem (the `$homme` variable).

You should switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements with bound variables.

In PDO your query would be something like:

```
// open PDO database connection
$sql = 'INSERT INTO commande (id,homme,quantiteh) VALUES (:id, :homme, :quantiteh)';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':homme' => $homme, ':quantiteh' => $quantiteh));
```

Comment: this single quote thing seems to be a theme today, second question i've seen where that was the issue

Comment: sorry but i don't understand i have already try all quotes lol and it's don't work !!
Please can you repair it !

I try to use PDO, i think i change all mysql_connect at the end by a file with PDO connect

Comment: thanks a lot for the PDO !!! i try that now ! but i don't understand what quotes i must add

Comment: @AlexMoody When you use placeholders / bound variables you don't have to use any quotes.